# Si se llegara por reversión a la ronda 0 de un hash SHA256 ¿Es posible descifrar el mensaje original?

Tags: criptografía, sha256

He leido que alguien llegó a descifrar 17 rondas de un hash 256.

Mi pregunta es si se llegara a descifrar las 64 rondas ¿Es posible romper el cifrado del mensaje de la inicialización del sha256?

Answer (score 0):

No es posible descifrar el mensaje porque dos mensajes pueden tener el mismo hash... Cada 2^256 hashes puede haber un mensaje diferente.

> 2^256 = 115792089237316195423570985008687907853269984665640564039457584007913129639936
> Aproximadamente 115*10^(3+6*12) = 115*10^3*10^72
> Ciento quince mil duodecillones
>
> - [https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duodecillón](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duodecill%C3%B3n)

Pero sí es posible crackearlo y encontrar sus posibles mensajes.

Para encontrar al menos uno de los posibles mensajes hay que comprobar el hash de cada uno de los 2^256 mensajes.

Si se descifró 17 rondas de las 64, quedan 47 rondas, entonces hay que diseñar un script que calcule el hash, solamente hasta la ronda 47, pero aún así la cantidad 2^256 no cambia.

Esto solamente haría que para encontrar cada posible mensaje sea un %36 (64/47) más rápido.